# A bag contains 4 Black and 3 Red balls, 2 balls are drawn one by one without replacement, what is the probability of both being red?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I  tried searching the internet regarding the **third approach i did**, but did not find any explanation for the same, here i have tried approaching this problem in 3 different ways.

**approach 1:**

since two balls are drawn **without** replacement, this can be treated as

$P (\text{selecting $2$ out of $7$ balls such that both are red})$

$=\frac{^3C_2}{^{7}C_2}$

**approach 2:**
$P (\text{select 1 R out of 3R })\times$ $P (\text{select 1 out of 2 remaining R })$
$=\frac{^3C_1}{7C_1}\times$$\frac{^2C_1}{6C_1}$

**approach 3:**

$P (\text{selecting 1 out of 3 R and then 1 out of 2 R balls in the second draw })$
$=\frac{N(RR)}{{N(RR)+N(RB)+N(BR)+N(BB)}}$
$=\frac{^3C_1\times^2C_1}{^3C_1\times^2C_1+^3C_1\times^4C_1+^4C_1\times^3C_1+^4C_1\times^3C_1}$

all the above approaches give *correct* answer, but i am not sure how **approach 1** and **approach 2** are equivalent,
clearly this is a case of conditional probability without replacement, in the first case, i take 2 balls simultaneously out of 7 and compute probability of both being red, that is same as drawing 2 balls without replacement! 
is this the correct way to approach a problem?

in the **approach 3** , i tried calculating the sample space where 2 balls are drawn without replacement, where there are four cases:

- Red in first and Red in second draw
- Red in first and Black in second draw
- Black in first and Red in second draw
- Black in first and Black in second draw

I am quite unsure about the validity of **approach 3!**
I am not sure if this is the right way to approach a problem.

Comment: Logic is always the right way. All 3 approaches are logical and conform the laws of probability.

Comment: This is a nice example of how multiple approaches to the same problem, if all are correctly thought through, will come to the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All $3$ approaches are okay.

Number the red balls by $1,2,3$ and number the black balls by $4,5,6,7$

Then you could say that **approach1** is linked with a probability space where: $$\Omega=\{\{i,j\}\mid i,j\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}\text{ and }i\neq j\}$$

Here $|\Omega|=\binom72=21$ agreeing with the denominator in approach1.

Also you could say that **approach3** is linked with a probability space where: $$\Omega=\{\langle i,j\rangle\}\mid i,j\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}\text{ and }i\neq j\}$$

Here $|\Omega|=7\times6=42$ agreeing with the denominator in approach3.

Concerning **approach2** (my favorite) both spaces can be used but actually we do not meet any impact of a choice for a probability space.

If $E_i$ denotes the event that the $i$-th ball is red for $i=1,2$ then we apply:$$P(\text{both balls are red})=P(E_1\cap E_2)=P(E_1)P(E_2\mid E_1)=\frac37\frac26$$

Calculating such probability we are not even aware of any underlying probability space.

Comment: in case of approach 2 and approach 3 , denominator is same, is it correct to infer that the denominator in approach 2 is the total number of sample points in the probability space when we approach this using conditional probability. However, it is exciting to see the variation in sample points when approached using approach 1, is it valid to say that selecting 2 red balls one after the other leads to increase in the probability space, which we see in approach  2 and 3 ?

Comment: Actually the approach that is used does not really *determine* the probability space. It only *points in the direction of some underlying probability space* in the sense that the calculation of the probability can be (more) easily understood if that space is applied.

Comment: You are correct in stating concerning approach2 that the probability space used for approach3 "fits better" than the probability space used in approach1. If $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is prescribed by $\langle i,j\rangle\mapsto i$ and $Y:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is prescribed by $\langle i,j\rangle\mapsto j$ then $E_1=\{X\in\{1,2,3\}\}$ and $E_2=\{Y\in\{1,2,3\}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ represent red balls and $B$ black balls

$P(R)=3/7$

$P(B)=4/7$

Therefore $P(RR) = \frac37 \cdot \frac26$

Ans = $6/42$